# brainternet how to output get_term_meta from a select field

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy-terms

I just added [Tax-meta script](https://github.com/bainternet/Tax-Meta-Class/)

to my theme and its nice its working with text fields but I have a select field which I cannot figure out.

$my_meta->addSelect($prefix.'eye_color',

```
array('amber'=>'Amber','blue'=>'Blue','brown'=>'Brown','gray'=>'Gray','green'=>'Green','hazel'=>'Hazel'),
  array('name'=> __('Eye Color','tax-meta'), 
  'std'=> array('amber')));
```

output:

```
$eye_color = get_term_meta($term_id,'opname_eye_color');
echo $eye_color;
```

the output above gives me (array) instead of any result from the select field,anyone that worked with this before?

thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Im sorry but Im posting the solution I did a mistake in get_term_meta
figuret it out by adding `$term->term_id instead of $term_id`

so added:

```
$term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );
```

and finaly worked the below code:

```
$eye_color = get_term_meta($term->term_id,'opname_eye_color',true);

echo $eye_color;
```